# what is the pronunciation of boys' with both possessive s and plural s?

Tags: possessives, plural-forms, phonetics

We are having a debate about the pronunciation of boys' with a plural s and a possessive s.

> Is there a pause at the end of the s or we just pronounce it with no pauses? is there a rule we should know about it?

Comment: The possessive apostrophe in English never affects pronunciation. This is probably one reason why many people, even native speakers, make apostrophe errors in written English.

Comment: We don't even stress (pause) at the apostrophe?

Comment: No stress, no pauses. **the boys**, **the boy's** and **the boys'** are all pronounced the same. When followed by a vowel or another sibilant, it joins onto the next phoneme: When followed by a consonant, it is followed only by the gap normally required before that consonant.

Answer (score 2):

No difference whatsoever.  As JavaLatte's comment says,

> No stress, no pauses. **the boys**, **the boy's** and the **boys'** are all pronounced the same.

Since it's impossible to *hear* any difference, you have to understand what is meant from context.

The only exception may be a *slight* difference in pronunciation with words where the plural is spelled with an "es" rather than an "s":

> The **foxes** ran into their burrow.
>
> The **fox's** burrow was beneath an old tree.

However, I imagine this depends on individual diction.  Some people will exaggerate the "e" sound more than others – so, again, it's better to rely on context.

Comment: RIght, and very simple indeed.